# Delphi: How to override ShortDateFormat?

Tags: delphi, localization, date-format

i realize that `ShortDateFormat` variable represents the user's preferences.

i also realize that if settings change, Delphi will automatically refresh the `ShortDateFormat` variable with the user's settings.

```
mm/dd/yy
```

i have a customer who wants all "short dates" to be displayed in a particular, but they don't want to their Windows preferences.

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

What is a good way to globally, in my application, change the `ShortDateFormat` variable, given that it can be reset at any time?

**Note:** example date format masks in code format included to make the post more visually appealing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with François, but I want to mention another option: set

```
Application.UpdateFormatSettings := False;
```

to prevent automatic updating of format settings when they are changed globally in Windows.

Comment: hehe. I was just about to add that!

Comment: I think that ShortDateFormat etc. are changed everytime you log in to Windows, or even just unlock the workstation. So this is very important.

Comment: That little gem (`Application.UpdateFormatSettings`) is the secret i was hoping for. Thanks to that i don't have to put the code in `Application.OnIdle`   >.>

Answer (score 9):

Have your own FormatSettings and use it explictly with all the format routines instead of using the implicit version.

It has also the advantage of being Thread safe.

```
function DateTimeToStr(const DateTime: TDateTime): string;

function DateTimeToStr(const DateTime: TDateTime; const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): string;
```

**Update**: to avoid your application to react to locale changes, you can change `Application.UpdateFormatSettings` to `False`.
It is defaulted to `True` in `TApplication.Create`.
But beware this is not 100% bulletproof for all settings as some routines go get the ThreadLocale directly.

Comment: There's just too many places in the software to change *every* last one. They really want it global. Plus, some of the code is shared, i don't want everyone getting it.